# How to get count of pos/neg/neu scored sentences

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def sent_dictionary__sentence_(text):
    token_dictionary = {}
    neg_count = []
    pos_count = []
    neu_count = []
    lexicon_keys = lexicon_dictionary.keys()
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    for sentence in sentences:
            tokens = apply_lemmatization(remove_punctuation(word_tokenize(str(sentence))))
            for token in tokens:
                if token in lexicon_keys:
                    token_dictionary[token] = token_dictionary.get(token, 0) + lexicon_dictionary[token]
                    new_token_dict = token_dictionary
                    txt_values = list(new_token_dict.values())
                    if sum(txt_values) == 0:
                        neu_count.append(sentence)
                    if sum(txt_values) > 0:
                        pos_count.append(sentence)
                    if sum(txt_values) < 0:
                        neg_count.append(sentence)
    print(len(neg_count))
    print(len(neu_count))
    print(len(pos_count))
```

What I am trying to do:

I have a text document, that I want to split up by sentences, then split by word so I can see if the words in the sentence is in the SentiWordNet dictionary. If the word is in the [SentiWord dictionary](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/)... have the associated score with the word, and add the scores if there are multiple of the same word.

Then with this information, I want to add the scores of the words in each sentence, and print out how many positive sentences there were, how many negative, and how many neutral.

When I tried to use it on a text document with 152 sentences, I got 1473 for positive, 
31 for negative,
1203 for neutral, which is obviously wrong. What can I do for this code to actually work?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I *think* I fixed it. Here is updated code if anyone was curious:

```
def sent_dictionary__sentence_(text):
    token_dictionary = {}
    neg_count = []
    pos_count = []
    neu_count = []
    lexicon_keys = lexicon_dictionary.keys()
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
    for sentence in sentences:
            tokens = apply_lemmatization(remove_punctuation(word_tokenize(str(sentence))))
            for token in tokens:
                if token in lexicon_keys:
                    token_dictionary[token] = token_dictionary.get(token, 0) + lexicon_dictionary[token]
                    new_token_dict = token_dictionary
                    txt_values = list(new_token_dict.values())
    for sentence in sentences:
            if sum(txt_values) == 0:
                neu_count.append(sentence)
            if sum(txt_values) > 0:
                pos_count.append(sentence)
            if sum(txt_values) < 0:
                neg_count.append(sentence)
    print("neg count: " + str(len(neg_count)))
    print("neu count: " + str(len(neu_count)))
    print("pos count: " + str(len(pos_count)))
```

Edit:

No I did not fix it. I use "I am able. I am unable." to test. I am able is positive. I am unable is negative. So the output should be:

```
neg count: 1
pos count: 1
```

Instead it says: pos count: 2

Edit:

I got this piece of advice, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

"I think the biggest problem with your code is that text_values isn't being saved anywhere after each iteration, so the final value inside of it will be whatever it was on the last iteration of the loop. You should create three variables, one for each tone count, and increment one per cycle of the for loop. Then you don't even need the second for loop and can just print the values out."

Comment: That is coorect. You are counting sentences more than once for maybe all three categories. So if in a sentence there are 5 negative words, The sentence will be added five time.

Comment: @MegaIng any advice on how i can prevent that from happening?